# openAI DALL-E ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pytorch, openai-api

I installed DALL-E following the instructions on https://github.com/openai/DALL-E

and got :
---> 10 from dall_e          import map_pixels, unmap_pixels, load_model
11 from IPython.display import display, display_markdown
12

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dall_e'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it helped when I changed which Python version I was using.

It fixed my issue when I changed mine from 3.7.- to 3.10.7.